# Variance of a location-scale transformed density

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, variance, density-function

NOTE:  I originally wrote this question by trying to transcribe the original problem according to my understanding, and in the process I introduced some problems.  I used 'asterisks' as a multiplication, mainly because as a CS student that was a norm when programming multiplications, and I was ignorant how in other circles that could be problematic.  Originally I also believed that $f$ by itself was a pdf, and not necessarily $f\{\}$. I've since deleted that transcription and replaced it with a screenshot of the problem itself, and hopefully that will do a better job that my first attempt to communicate the problem I'm trying to solve.

The question is as follows.

[image]

I think part of the confusion I've been having is whether to read "f" by itself as a representation of a pdf, or if $f\{(x - \mu)/\sigma\}$ is "f".  If it is the latter case, then "g" is $f\{(x - \mu)/\sigma\}/\sigma$, and not $f$ times $\{(x - \mu)/\sigma\}/\sigma$, the latter being how I originally thought what was being stated.

Comment: The notations in your attempts are very messy.  Try to get them in order first.  Do not use unnecessary and confusing asterisks ($*$).

Comment: @Zhanxiong ... unless asterisks mean convolution which wouldn't be abnormal for densities ; said otherwise, I don't understand how a density times a density could still be a density...

Comment: @JeanMarie I am aware of "$*$" is used as a standard notation for convolution (of two densities) -- however, this is clearly not the case in OP's post (he got only one density $f$, $(x - \mu)/\sigma$ is just an argument).  So my interpretation is $g(x)$ is defined as the product of $\sigma^{-1}$ and $f$ evaluated at $(x - \mu)/\sigma$.  As for the wording "a density times another density*, I hope it does not mean $f$ "asterisk" $(x - \mu)/\sigma$.  Anyway, this wording plays no role in the problem itself.

Comment: Right, the asterisk is meant to represent a multiplication.   I included it to be explicit.  I imagine this form of notation must be confusing, and I apologize about that.  So, the equation should be read as g is equal to density f times the quantity of x minus mu divided by sigma, then divided by sigma.

Comment: @StanleyYu "*The asterisk is meant to represent a multiplication*" does not make any sense -- what is meant by "a function multiply a number/argument"???  As I commented above and clarified in my answer, the asterisk is completely superfluous and should be removed.  And the expression $f((x - \mu)\sigma^{-1})$ is interpreted as "the density $f$ **evaluated at the point** $(x - \mu)\sigma^{-1}$.  Did you get it now?

Comment: Now that you accepted my answer, I infer you have understood the full context.  Given that, may I suggest modifying the post title to "*Variance of a location-scale transformed density*" or "*Variance of the density from a location-scale family*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\real}{\mathbb{R}}$

First of all, the correct expression of $g$ should be $g(x) = \sigma^{-1}f((x - \mu)\sigma^{-1})$ (that is, the "$*$" in the definition of $g$ in your post should be removed).  In terms of random variables, $g$ is the density of $X = \sigma Y + \mu$, if we know $Y \sim f$.  This expression then makes the calculation of $\operatorname{Var}(X)$ (equivalently, the variance of $g$) almost immediate:
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(X) = \operatorname{Var}(\sigma Y + \mu) = \sigma^2\operatorname{Var}(Y) = \sigma^2,
\end{align}
as $\operatorname{Var}(Y) = 1$.

It remains to show the density of $X$ is indeed $g$, which can be verified by first evaluating the distribution function of $X$:
\begin{align}
F_X(x) = P[X \leq x] = P[\sigma Y + \mu \leq x] = P[Y \leq \sigma^{-1}(x - \mu)]
= F_Y(\sigma^{-1}(x - \mu)), 
\end{align}
whence the density of $X$ is
\begin{align}
f_Y(x)= F_X'(x) = F_Y'(\sigma^{-1}(x - \mu)) = \sigma^{-1}f(\sigma^{-1}(x - \mu)) = g(x). 
\end{align}
This completes the proof.

Alternatively, a direct calculation of $\operatorname{Var}(X)$ through $E[X^2] - (E[X])^2$ is also viable (the key is then to make every change of variable step correct):
\begin{align}
 & E[X] \\
=& \int_\real xg(x)dx \\
=& \int_\real x\frac{f(\sigma^{-1}(x - \mu))}{\sigma}dx \\
=& \int_\real (\sigma y + \mu)f(y)dy \tag{$y = \sigma^{-1}(x - \mu)$} \\
=& \mu\int_\real f(y)dy + \sigma\int_\real yf(y) dy \\
=& \mu, \\[1em]
 & E[X^2] \\
=& \int_\real x^2g(x)dx \\
=& \int_\real x^2\frac{f(\sigma^{-1}(x - \mu))}{\sigma}dx \\
=& \int_\real (\sigma y + \mu)^2f(y)dy \tag{$y = \sigma^{-1}(x - \mu)$} \\
=& \sigma^2\int_\real y^2f(y)dy + 2\mu\sigma\int_\real yf(y)dy + 
\mu^2\int_\real f(y) dy \\
=& \sigma^2 + \mu^2.
\end{align}
In the above derivation, we used conditions: the expectation of $f$ is $0$ (i.e., $\int_\real yf(y)dy = 0$), and the variance of $f$ is $1$ (i.e., $\int_\real y^2f(y)dy = 1$). Therefore,
$$\operatorname{Var}(X) = E[X^2] - (E[X])^2 = \sigma^2 + \mu^2 - \mu^2 = \sigma^2.$$
This completes the proof.

---

Background:  For a given density function $f$ with mean $0$ and variance $1$, the family of distributions
$$\{f_{\mu, \sigma}(x) = \sigma^{-1}f((x - \mu)/\sigma): \mu \in \real, \sigma > 0\}$$
is called a *location-scale family*.  For example, the family of normal distributions $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ is a location-scale family.  It is well-known that the variance of the standard normal distribution is $1$ and the variance of a general normal distribution is $\sigma^2$.  This exercise asserts that the same property holds for any location-scale family (where the expectation and variance of the base density $f_{0, 1} = f$ are $0$ and $1$ respectively).